# How to integrate the sql server in cakephp

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

Here is my connection string.

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'SAI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS',
    'login' => 'sa',
    'password' => '123',
    'database' => 'SFAC_Connectmp',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

- I am able to login the sql server using the above credentials and it works fine
- I have checked all the options from the sql server manager.
  eg. -Sql server and browser services are running fine.
     -Remote server connection is checked 
     -windows firewall is off
  -Still i get the error 
  A Database connection using "Sqlserver" was missing or unable to connect.
  The database server returned this error: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the host name?

Try adding the port to the host with hostname:port

Is the server local? Does it work with localhost?
Is it on the local network? Does it work with it's LAN ip?

Have you installed/enabled the php sqlsrv driver?

[Try this](http://about-opensource.blogspot.in/2012/06/cake-php-231-with-sql-server-2005-or.html)